# Retrive records of a table with out related tables' records by Entity Framework?

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6

When I get records of a table by EF such as

```
db.cities.Tolist();
```

returns all records of the `City` table and related tables records but I want get city table records **only** .

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework supports 3 ways to load related data - eager loading, lazy loading and explicit loading.

In your case, you can either go for lazy loading or explicit loading.

**Lazy Loading** is enabled by default, so until you access a related property it's data won't be fetched from the database.

**Explicit loading**, first you need to disable Lazy loading:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext 
{ 
    public DatabaseContext() 
    { 
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; 
    } 
}
```

Then you can load related entities using `Load()`.

```
var city = context.cities.FirstOrDefault();
context.Entry(city).Reference(p => p.Buildings).Load();
```

Assuming cities table refers to Buildings table.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use lazy loading feature of EF like below. Add this line just before any ToList() calls

```
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

also you can configure this behavior globally by setting the property in your DBContext Constructor like below.

```
public partial class SchoolDBEntities : DbContext
{
    public SchoolDBEntities(): base("name=SchoolDBEntities")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }    

}
```